# Codeigniter using ms access database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, ms-access

So I using access database(*mdb).
This my code and success to connect:

```
$db['test']['hostname'] = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\blabla.mdb';
$db['test']['username'] = '';
$db['test']['password'] = '';
$db['test']['database'] = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\blabla.mdb';
$db['test']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['test']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['test']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['test']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['test']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['test']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['test']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

And now I want to using accessdb from other computer.
This accessdb(*mdb) has been shared and I make map network drive(Z:).

So I was change hostname and database but its failed:

```
$db['test']['hostname'] = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=Z:\blabla.mdb';
$db['test']['database'] = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=Z:\blabla.mdb';
```

And I try this to:

```
$db['test']['hostname'] = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=\\10.0.0.107\share\blabla.mdb';
$db['test']['database'] = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=\\10.0.0.107\share\blabla.mdb';
```

But it still error:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: D:\folder\folder\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124
```

and even i try to connect with php
and this is the result [php using msaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313154/php-using-msaccess)

Comment: May help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178860/code-igniter-cakephp-and-ms-access

Comment: @Remou already read that before make this question :(

Comment: @duskwuff i dont want to, but its a request from user

Comment: This development stuff would be easy if it wasn't for those damn users/customers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the default IIS IUSER cannot access files over a network share.
the workaround is detailed here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207671.

I would highly recommend using SQL Server (Express Edition if nothing else) than an access file - you will get a much improved experience + you will be able to migrate easier as the site expands if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread for a similar problem: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/93160/. Says you should try loading loading the odbc driver manually from your controller:

```
$this->load->database();
$this->db->dbdriver = “odbc”;
```

It also says that for some reason the database config is not available in the odbc driver:

> system/database/drivers/odbc/odbc_driver.php

So you may also have to go in there and load the database config manually.

Answer (score 1):

```
$db['second']['hostname'] = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=C:/wamp/www/ket_noi_access/test1.mdb";//C:\wamp\www\ket_noi_access
$db['second']['username'] = "ADODB.Connection";
$db['second']['password'] = "xxxxx";
$db['second']['database'] = "C:/wamp/www/ket_noi_access/test1.mdb";
$db['second']['dbdriver'] = "odbc";
$db['second']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['second']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['second']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['second']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['second']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['second']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['second']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['second']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['second']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['second']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

code

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->legacy_db = $this->load->database('second',true);
}
function LayDanhSach(){
    $this->legacy_db->select('*');
    $this->legacy_db->from('ban');
    $query = $this->legacy_db->get();
    $kq=$query->result();
    $this->legacy_db->close();
    //$this->db->close();
    return $kq;    
}

$this->load->model("ban_model");
$ds=$this->ban_model->LayDanhSach();
$st="This is demo multi database and msaccess connect <br>";        
$st.=json_encode($ds);
$this->data['content']=$st;//json_encode($ds);//echo json_encode($ds);
$this->load->view('index_view2',$this->data,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked read/write access to that file? If your php app is running on IIS, then your IIS' user account will need to have read/write permissions to that file, not the user account you use to login to your computer.

Comment: this is supposed to be a comment, not a answer?

Comment: yes i read this so many time,and it still didn't work, i using apache,and i already check read/write access to mdb file.....

Answer (score 0):

Check what user your PHP program is running under. List a directory content with PHP to check. Consider that user running your PHP can also has no mapping of `Z` you made under you own username.

Answer (score 0):

After many searches (nothing from the mentioned solution worked) I found a different solution, on some ms Access db's you can only connect using double slashes in the connection string (not in the database path):

```
$db['test']['hostname'] = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\\path\\to\my.mdb';
$db['test']['username'] = '';
$db['test']['password'] = '';
$db['test']['database'] = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\path\to\my.mdb';
$db['test']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['test']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['test']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['test']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['test']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['test']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['test']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

not sure what is the cause because I was able to connect on some Access db's (same server, same folder, same Access version) using single slashes and double slashes didn't work, think it's a silly joke of the same guy who worked on IE :-(

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
$db['access']['hostname'] = 'DNS name created by me'; // or ip address
$db['access']['username'] = '';
$db['access']['password'] = '';
$db['access']['database'] = '';
$db['access']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['access']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['access']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['access']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['access']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['access']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['access']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['access']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['access']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['access']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['access']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```