# php using msaccess

Tags: php, database, ms-access, odbc

Because no one answer my question [Codeigniter using ms access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274274/codeigniter-using-ms-access-database) , i make new question i not using codeigniter

if I using mdb from my computer it works but if i using mdb from another computer in my network

i got error this is my CODE

```
<?php

$connect = odbc_connect("testdb", "", "");
$query = "SELECT * FROM ACGroup";
$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);

while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
  $name = odbc_result($result, 1);
  echo("$name");
}

?>
```

i make odbc where the data its from another computer in my network

```
"testdb" are data sourcename and database \\ip\folder\testdb.mdb
```

and i got this error

```
   Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] 
    The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '(unknown)'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.,
     SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect in D:\blabla\coba.php on line 3
```

I already try folder setting but it not work

Answer (score 0):

The ODBC connection string you are using (`"testdb"`) does not even specify a database driver, much less a database file. You will need to read up on the appropriate format for `$dsn`. ([The php.net page](https://www.php.net/odbc_connect) even has a few examples for Access files.)

Comment: If "testdb" is a local odbc data source configured on the system, his connection string is fine as the first value represents a valid user or system dsn name and the other two fields would be a username and password if needed.

Comment: @mjayt thanks for respond my question,and i had complete my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem possibly lies in the permissions your Apache user has on the mdb file.

Go to your mdb file, right-clik on the file -> Properties ->Security tab and see if your Apache user is on the User Groups that have access/control on the mdb file.

In order to see/change your Apache user, go to Control Panel-> Administrative Tools -> Services, right-click on Apache service -> Properties -> Logon tab. In the Log on as option, see if the user selected belongs to the User Groups that have access to mdb file. If not, create one and add it to the User Groups and then use it as the Apache account.