# Accessing Secure Access Databases with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-access, database-connection

If I want to connect to a secure Access DB (ie through an MDW file) via CodeIgniter, what are the settings I need here:

```
$db['test']['hostname'] = '';
$db['test']['username'] = '';
$db['test']['password'] = '';
$db['test']['database'] = '';
$db['test']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['test']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['test']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['test']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['test']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['test']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['test']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I assume the connection string should be something like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:System Database=system.mdw;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Although I'm quite happy to be corrected on that :)

### Edit

In light of a couple of answers, I'll clarify something. I want to access an MS Access file through a workgroup. Essentially what I'm after is this - assuming that connection string is correct, which I think it is - which bits of it go where? I had assumed this:

```
$db['test']['hostname'] = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:System Database=system.mdw";
```

But does the username and password need to go in that string, since they'll be used in system.mdw, or in the ['username'] and ['password'] keys respectively? Or have I got the wrong end of the stick and put something where it shouldn't be? Cos it don't connect...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter using ms access database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274274/codeigniter-using-ms-access-database)

Comment: @Ryan, I had seen that one, but it doesn't deal with accessing it via a MDW file ...

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; 
$db['default']['username'] = 'myUsername'; // your username
$db['default']['password'] = 'myPassword'; // your password
$db['default']['database'] = 'database_name'; // your database name
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = 'tbl_';//set a prefix that automatically comes with all table name. for eg: tbl_tablename.
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;// if true that display specific errors
$db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: he is not using mysql as database

Answer (score 0):

It's like this.I'm assuming your database and website located in the same server.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'YOUR DB USERNAME';
$db['default']['password'] = 'YOUR DB PASSWORD';
$db['default']['database'] = 'YOUR DB';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = 'IF DB HAS PREFIX';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```