# How to connect remote ms access database in PHP Web Application

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-access, odbc

i want to connect remote ms access db from codeigniter framework.
i tried it with odbc connection but it's not connecting.
remote pc is server and have windows server 2012.

connection string i used:

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Server=192.168.0.1;Dbq=C:\_Database\_Backend\MasterBE.mdb;Uid=sa;pwd=sa;
```

codeigniter db connection:

```
$db['accessdb']['hostname'] = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Server=192.168.0.1;Dbq=C:\_Database\_Backend\MasterBE.mdb;Uid=sa;pwd=sa;';
$db['accessdb']['username'] = 'sa';
$db['accessdb']['password'] = 'sa';
$db['accessdb']['database'] = 'C:\_Database\_Backend\MasterBE.mdb';
$db['accessdb']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['accessdb']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['accessdb']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['accessdb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['accessdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['accessdb']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['accessdb']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['accessdb']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['accessdb']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['accessdb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['accessdb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Please help me,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter using ms access database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274274/codeigniter-using-ms-access-database)

Comment: As far as I know the Access ODBC driver does not work over TCP/IP. It only works on the local computer or with file sharing.