# codeigniter access database on different fileserver

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an MS Access database on a fileserver, web application on a separate web server, both servers are on the same network.

Is there any way for me to connect web application to said access database without moving it to the web server?

Thanks

p.s.

Both servers are windows.

Comment: Is the web server linux, windows, or other?

Comment: Question is too broad. What have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: Having personally worked with MS Access databases and attempting to connect to them via CodeIgniter, my experience was that it is not possible. Even if the access database is located on the server, you will most likely not be able to connect to it. In my case, the Access database was a .accdb file.

Comment: check this post, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274274/codeigniter-using-ms-access-database

Comment: this one seemed to work too, but you'll need to adapt to CI: http://rajeevphp2011.blogspot.pt/2012/04/odbc-connection-with-ms-access-database.html

Comment: It's not so much connecting to access that I am concerened with, it's the possibility of connecting to the database when it  is not stored within the webserver.